# Random background images slideshow using backstretch plugin

Tags: jquery

Here is the deal. I'm using a plugin called backstretch wich fullscreen my background images and making a slideshow of it.

This is what I have [for now](http://jsfiddle.net/Autodealers/32KE5/) ([website of the plugin](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)).

Now, I want the images be random each time. Say I have 3 images, it would be like:

```
2, 3, 1
3, 1, 2
1, 2, 3
1, 3, 2
```

In a line this would be: `2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2`

Note: images must avoid repeating themself like: `2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3`

Anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `math.Random();` to provide a random index from your array place this within a while loop and do it till you get a different number. ie.

```
oldIndex = index;
while (oldIndex == index) {
   index = Math.floor((Math.random()*images.length));
   }
```

EDIT:
To start with a random image use the random method before you call backstretch

```
index = Math.floor((Math.random()*images.length));
$.backstretch(images[index], {
    speed: 500
});
```

Your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32KE5/9/)

EDIT 2:

After discussing with the OP requirements (in comments), they required a not entirely random slider. It was required to ensure all indexes were used before selecting any of them again then when empty then reset.

By populating a list of indexes into a separate array we can then remove from the array as we use them until empty and then repopulate, We also mantain the previous index so that even on resetting that a image wouldn't repeat. The final result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/32KE5/12/)

Comment: Thnx for your reply, almost there! The first image must also to be random each time. Can you take a look for that?

Comment: Great, thnx! 1 More thing. It seems the order will be most time like this: 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1. I words, the loop now has 3 images. Those 3 images must be displayed first when going to the next loop. Sorry if I'm unclear, but can you guess what I mean?

Comment: ok so no not entirely random more like a random choice of the remaining indexes until empty then reset?

Comment: Exactly! That is what I mean/want

Comment: ok [this](http://jsfiddle.net/32KE5/12/) should be it, if you look at the javascript console you can see it never repeats the same one and does them all before resetting.

Comment: The only thing I edited is the var index = 0 to var index = -1, so that the first image also get the change to start ;)